# Is there a way i can add implicit ordering to improve this code?

Tags: scala, binary-search-tree, typeclass, implicit

```
sealed trait BinaryTree[+A]

case object Leaf extends BinaryTree[Nothing]

case class Branch[A](value: A, leftTree: BinaryTree[A], rightTree: BinaryTree[A]) extends BinaryTree[A]

object BinaryTree extends App {

  // --------------------Methods Specific to BST ------------------------------
  //given a list of elements -> create BST from it

  def createBST[A](nodes: List[A]): BinaryTree[A] = {
    def bstHelper[A](tree: BinaryTree[A], newKey: A): BinaryTree[A] = tree match {
      case Leaf => Branch(newKey, Leaf, Leaf)
      case Branch(x, ltree, rtree) => {
        if (newKey == x)
          Branch(x, ltree, Branch(newKey, Leaf, rtree))
        else if (newKey.toString.toInt > x.toString.toInt)
          Branch(x, ltree, bstHelper(rtree, newKey))
        else
          Branch(x, bstHelper(ltree, newKey), rtree)
      }
    }

    nodes.foldLeft[BinaryTree[A]](Leaf)((z, b) => bstHelper(z, b)) 
  }
```

I want to have improvement over this part: `else if (newKey.toString.toInt > x.toString.toInt)`, This will throw error in case if i try to create BST with String.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward:

```scala
def createBST[A](nodes: List[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): BinaryTree[A] = { // here declare the implicit Ordering
    def bstHelper[A](tree: BinaryTree[A], newKey: A): BinaryTree[A] = tree match {
      case Leaf => Branch(newKey, Leaf, Leaf)
      case Branch(x, ltree, rtree) => {
        if (newKey == x)
          Branch(x, ltree, Branch(newKey, Leaf, rtree))
        else if (ord.gt(newKey, x)) // here use the Ordering
          Branch(x, ltree, bstHelper(rtree, newKey))
        else
          Branch(x, bstHelper(ltree, newKey), rtree)
      }
    }

    nodes.foldLeft[BinaryTree[A]](Leaf)((z, b) => bstHelper(z, b)) 
  }
```

Comment: type mismatch;
 found   : newKey.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
        `else if (ord.gt(newKey, x)) // here use the Ordering`

@Gaël J Please have a look. I am getting following error.